# Online attendance system

Tags: algorithm-design, implementation

This summer I have made a website for my school's NHS program and integrated it with google scripts to automate tasks such as accessing how many hours users have and to allow members to view how many volunteer hours they themselves have earned. The next step I want to take is to automate the sign-in process for each student's attendance. I would like members to be able to come into a meeting, log in on their google account, and mark themselves as present on the website.

The problem is that I need a system such that members must be at the meeting in order to mark themselves as present. A simple code given at the meeting which members must enter on the website will not work, for members could text other members the code that was at the meeting, thus circumventing the whole system. It is really important that the system only allows people who are present to mark themselves as present since we have very strict attendance policies.

The system last year required students to mark themselves as present on a sign in piece of paper. Not only did trouble the officers with having to manually enter all of the attendance information in, but it also caused really long lines to form outside of the room just for sign-in.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: err, what's a NHS program?

Comment: It's an organization for volunteer work, the National Honor Society. The details are irrelevant, I just need a way for them to mark themselves as present in the meetings.

Comment: Would it be more feasible to use a system of "members claim to be there and the authority approves / declines this claim"? Or maybe set a hotspot up on-site  which only accepts local, direct wifi connections and use this as the core mechanic?

Comment: Both of those are possibilities, but the challenge would be to make the system convenient for both the members and the authority. The hotspot is an interesting idea, but I have no idea how I could set that up to make it clickable with a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Generate a list of unique coupon codes in a format of your choice.
2. Print them out prior to the meeting /event/ ceremony. Like lottery tickets.
3. Hand them out to attendees, one for each kid. At the end I guess.
4. Each kid then later enters the coupon code into a website to confirm attendance.
5. Repeat prior to the next event...

There's a question [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40834/want-to-generate-numeric-coupon-codes) regarding preparation of coupons.  Just formulate your generation algorithm carefully to avoid BUMH0LEs.

Comment: Internally couldn't I just generate a set of pseudo-random words which would be the coupons, and then for each store if it has already been used?

Comment: @2.71828-asy Err, I'm not really sure what you're asking...